# How to resize a series of images to a given total file size while keeping their relative size?

Tags: image-processing, files-and-directories

I have multiple image files, file1.jpeg, file2.png, file3.gif, ..., whose sizes are 984KB, 10MB, 5.1MB, .... I'd like to resize them so

1. Each image file, when open, have the same aspect ratio as the before;
2. The relative dimension of any two images are kept unchanged;
3. The total size is under but as close as possible to 9MB.

What's a good way to do this?

Comment: Presumably you would like the image dimension to be as large as possible?

Comment: Yes. But not larger than the original values.

Comment: I'm not sure that resizing the images is your best strategy (though it depends on what you want to do with the images in the end). What you are talking about is compressing the images, so why not resave the larger png and gifs as a (compressed) jpegs. By choosing the compression ratio, you can leave the dimensions of the images unchanged (hence not effecting your already smaller jpeg) and yet reduce the memory footprint.

Answer (score 2):

Scaling mixed GIF, JPEG and PNG images to achieve a total file size presents some unique problems. Here's a starting point to manipulate images by resizing the them while preserving their relative dimensions.

It seems that the best approach to getting nearest to the 9 MB goal is to save all the images as a single file type, e.g., PNG or JPEG.

Scaling the images files to achieve a total size needs a heuristic estimate of how each file should be adjusted. I've totaled the sizes of the files, and divided by the target size (9 MB, or 1 MB for the sample files). Each image will need to be optimized so its compressed file size is closest to its target value.

Import and export of images must allow for the different optional features of the file types, e.g., PNG files may be color-mapped, so there's a separate function for each type of compressed file. The relative aspect ratio is preserved for every file by using a `scale` factor to set the each file's dimensions.

The sample files present a worst-case set of images. Notably, I had better results with images that have more uniform characteristics. The resize functions have limitations:

- GIF files may have multiple images. Use the last one.
- JPEG compression level for the output files computed to make output files
  close to the input file size.
- PNG files may have multiple images. Use the last one. PNG files can
  be color-mapped, so retain the same number of colors.

Functions to resize images:

```
resizeGIF[fn_,scale_]:=Module[{img},
  img=Import[fn];
  If[Length[Import[fn,"ImageList"]]>1,img=Last@img];
  ExportString[ImageResize[img,Round@ImageDimensions[img]/Sqrt[scale],Resampling->"Nearest"],"GIF"]
]
jpegSize[img_,c_?NumberQ] := Module[
  {cl = Which[c<0,0,c>1,1,True,c]},
  ByteCount[ExportString[img,"JPEG",CompressionLevel->cl]]
]
resizeJPEG[fn_,scale_] := Module[{img,bytes,imgScaled},
  img = Import[fn];
  bytes = QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[FileSize[fn],"Bytes"]];
  imgScaled = ImageResize[img, Round@ImageDimensions[img]/Sqrt[scale]];
  ExportString[imgScaled,"JPEG", 
   CompressionLevel->NArgMin[{Abs[jpegSize[imgScaled,c,"JPEG"]-bytes],0<=c<=1.},c]]
]
resizePNG[fn_,scale_] := 
  Module[{mapLength = Length[Import[fn,"ColorMap"]],img},
  img = Import[fn];
  If[Length[Import[fn,"ImageList"]]>1,img = Last@img];
  If[mapLength == 0,
    ExportString[
      ImageResize[img,Round@ImageDimensions[img]/Sqrt[scale]],"PNG"],
    ExportString[
      ImageResize[img,Round@ImageDimensions[img]/Sqrt[scale], 
      Resampling -> "Nearest"],"PNG","ColorMapLength"->mapLength]
  ]
]
resizeImage[fn_,scale_]:=Module[
  {fileType=Lookup[extMap,"."<>ToLowerCase[FileExtension[fn]]]},
  Which[
    fileType==="GIF",resizeGIF[fn,scale],
    fileType==="JPEG",resizeJPEG[fn,scale],
    fileType==="PNG",resizePNG[fn,scale]
  ]
]
```

Setup and sample images:

```
extMap=<|".jpeg"->"JPEG",".jpg"->"JPEG",".gif"->"GIF",".png"->"PNG"|>;
exampleDir=DirectoryName[FindFile["ExampleData/rose.gif"]];
SetDirectory[exampleDir];
fileNames=FileNames[__~~Alternatives@@Keys[extMap],IgnoreCase->True];
sizeGoal=1024^2 (*9*1024^2*);
totalBytes=Total[FileByteCount/@fileNames];
scale=N[totalBytes/sizeGoal];
```

Compare the dimensions and sizes of the original files to the resized copies.

```
(*Splice introduced in MMA v12.1, otherwise use:*)
(*Splice[list_List]:=Sequence@@list*)
TableForm[
  Table[{fn,
    Splice@Import[fn,"ImageSize"],
    IntegerPart@QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[FileSize[fn],"Bytes"]],
    Splice@ImportString[file2=resizeImage[fn,scale],"ImageSize"],
    ByteCount[file2],
    100.*ByteCount[file2]/QuantityMagnitude[UnitConvert[FileSize[fn],"Bytes"]]},
  {fn,fileNames}],
TableHeadings->{None,{"file","h","w","bytes","h","w","bytes","percent"}}]
```

> ```
> file                  h   w   bytes   h   w   bytes   percent
> applepicking.jpg      480 640 347841  434 579 362312  104.16
> cellularautomaton.gif 64  35  1594    58  32  400     25.0941
> coneflower.jpg        150 113 63250   136 102 36864   58.283
> girlcloseup.jpg       580 580 264517  525 525 277496  104.907
> glasses.png           340 260 199862  308 235 169072  84.5944
> ocelot.jpg            200 200 19823   181 181 19456   98.1486
> pearls.png            150 150 180353  136 136 10240   5.67775
> photo.jpg             249 341 11357   225 309 11264   99.1811
> rose.gif              223 164 15799   202 148 19456   123.147
> spikey2.png           150 135 32092   136 122 29696   92.534
> turtle.jpg            200 119 10253   181 108 10240   99.8732
> wave.gif              100 100 133655  90  90  9216    6.89536
> ```

Previous results:

> ```
> file                  h   w   bytes   h   w   bytes   percent
> applepicking.jpg      480 640 347841  434 579 118056  33.9396
> cellularautomaton.gif 64  35  1594    58  32  2176    136.512
> coneflower.jpg        150 113 63250   136 102 16384   25.9036
> girlcloseup.jpg       580 580 264517  525 525 61440   23.2272
> glasses.png           340 260 199862  308 235 169072  84.5944
> ocelot.jpg            200 200 19823   181 181 12288   61.9886
> pearls.png            150 150 180353  136 136 11264   6.24553
> photo.jpg             249 341 11357   225 309 19456   171.313
> rose.gif              223 164 15799   202 148 24576   155.554
> spikey2.png           150 135 32092   136 122 29696   92.534
> turtle.jpg            200 119 10253   181 108 6400    62.4208
> wave.gif              100 100 133655  90  90  9728    7.27844
> ```

**Update:**

Replace functions to resize images. JPEG images are resized to be close to the size of input files. GIF and PNG color-mapped files are imported with "Nearest" resampling.